# onedrive javascript api sharing link requires account

Tags: office365, onedrive, javascript-api-for-office

I'm using the OneDrive Javascript API 7.0 against an Office 365 account.  The anonymous sharing link I'm being returned cannot be used by users without an Office 365 account.  This used to work correctly before the last week or so.  What am i doing wrong?

BTW, this occurs with the Microsoft Javascript sample picker at
https://dev.onedrive.com/sdk/js-v7/js-picker-open.htm
as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this in my advanced parameters

```
createLinkParameters: { type: "view", scope: "anonymous" }
```